# How to get element offset on angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

> I heve this html structure which represents a list of elements like a
>   tree. and on another part have some favorites element from this list.
>   What I want to achieve is when I click a favorite element to scroll to
>   the element in the list and mark it as selected. I have problems
>   calculating the offset top of the element relative to the tree-view
>   componentcause I have a treenode elementRef and I try to go on it's
>   parents but when he reach the final treenode in the tree structure the
>   parentElement is null. How can I compute the exact offset of the
>   element so I can scroll to it ? I don't want to incluje JQuery in my
>   project for this

```
<tree-view class="unit-subunit-list" ng-reflect-tree-data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" ng-reflect-tree-options="[object Object]"><tree class="tree-view" ng-reflect-nodes="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-focused="false">
    <div class="tree">
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><treenode ng-reflect-node="[object Object]">
    <div ng-reflect-class-name="tree-node tree-node-level-1" class="tree-node tree-node-level-1 tree-node-expanded">
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="toggle-children-wrapper">

        <span class="toggle-children"></span>
      </span>
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      <div class="node-content-wrapper">

        <treenodecontent ng-reflect-node="[object Object]"></treenodecontent><treenodetemplate><unit-subunit-item ng-reflect-node-model="[object Object]"><a class="ca-list-item">
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="ca-toggle-children-wrapper expanded">
        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
    </div>
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><div class="ca-item-content-wrapper">
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="unit">Olympics</span>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    </div>
<a></a></a></unit-subunit-item></treenodetemplate>
      </div>
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="tree-children">
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><div>
          <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><treenode ng-reflect-node="[object Object]">
    <div ng-reflect-class-name="tree-node tree-node-level-2" class="tree-node tree-node-level-2 tree-node-leaf">
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="toggle-children-placeholder">
      </span>
      <div class="node-content-wrapper">

        <treenodecontent ng-reflect-node="[object Object]"></treenodecontent><treenodetemplate><unit-subunit-item ng-reflect-node-model="[object Object]"><a class="ca-list-item">
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><div class="ca-item-content-wrapper">
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="subunit">
            <span>Administrator</span>
        </div>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="description">
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<a></a></a></unit-subunit-item></treenodetemplate>
      </div>
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
    </div>
  </treenode><treenode ng-reflect-node="[object Object]">
    <div ng-reflect-class-name="tree-node tree-node-level-2" class="tree-node tree-node-level-2 tree-node-leaf">
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="toggle-children-placeholder">
      </span>
      <div class="node-content-wrapper">

        <treenodecontent ng-reflect-node="[object Object]"></treenodecontent><treenodetemplate><unit-subunit-item ng-reflect-node-model="[object Object]"><a class="ca-list-item">
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><div class="ca-item-content-wrapper">
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="subunit">
            <span>Astronaut</span>
        </div>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="description">
            <span>Description</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<a></a></a></unit-subunit-item></treenodetemplate>
      </div>
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
    </div>
  </treenode><treenode ng-reflect-node="[object Object]">
    <div ng-reflect-class-name="tree-node tree-node-level-2" class="tree-node tree-node-level-2 tree-node-leaf">
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="toggle-children-placeholder">
      </span>
      <div class="node-content-wrapper">

        <treenodecontent ng-reflect-node="[object Object]"></treenodecontent><treenodetemplate><unit-subunit-item ng-reflect-node-model="[object Object]"><a class="ca-list-item">
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><div class="ca-item-content-wrapper">
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="subunit">
            <span>Lead</span>
        </div>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="description">
            <span>Description</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<a></a></a></unit-subunit-item></treenodetemplate>
      </div>
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
    </div>
  </treenode>
        </div>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </treenode>
    </div>
  </tree></tree-view>
```

Comment: Have you already tried using `scrollIntoView()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I have a reference to the nativeElement and I tryed, elementRef.scrollIntoView() the document does nothing, it might be that he cannot do it because of angular2 imbricated components, the reference points to the treenode which will be marked as active

Comment: Did you mean `elementRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView()` since it is actually a DOM method and not an Angular 2 one.

Comment: Yes, what I suppose is that it doesn't work because I have multiple components imbricated